# How to extract the words from the tree structure using Regex pattern

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

I need to extract the noun phrases from the tree structure, but i am unable to extract the nouns from the tree structure using regex pattern.

Here is the tree structure

(TOP (ADJP (JJ welcome) (PP (TO to) (NP (NNP Regular) (NNP Expression) (NNS learnings)))))

I need to extract all the words which are pos tags like NP,NNP,NNS etc.i.e; i need to get the words like Regular,Expression,learnings using regex pattern.

Can some one please help me how to get this.

Comment: I would recommend to parse it to actual tree structure in memory and then find what you want.

Comment: what will you extract for `NP`?

Comment: Not a job for regex (at least Java regex cannot support this). You can go through the string and build a tree.

Comment: Will regex help me in getting the words that i needed or do i need to switch to some other thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sure if this is what you've wanted but this will extract those words for you:

```
Pattern regexpPattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]?[a-z]+)\\)");
Matcher m = regexpPattern.matcher("your string");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```